# how to give conditional cellpadding value based on the browser version?

Tags: php, html, css

How to give conditional `cellpadding` based on the browser version?for example :

for IE7 I want to give `cellpadding=200` and for others browsers 100.

can I implement it using PHP?

if yes how to achieve this?

```
<table  class="popup"  id="nameFieldPopup" border="0" cellpadding="100" >
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

I have tried

```
[if IE] .popup {  
    width: 500px;  
    cellpadding: 100px 0;  
}
```

but its not working.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try IE specific css rule. for controlling "cellpadding" in CSS, you can simply use padding for table cells.

```
table#nameFieldPopup tr td { 
    padding: 100px; /* standard */
    *padding: 200px; /* IE 7 and below */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think conditional comments work inside the CSS file.

You could use conditional comments inside the HTML file, in order to to load a separate CSS file:

```
<!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
```

This file should contain

```
.popup td {
    padding: 200px; /*200 for IE7 as in your example*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!--[if !IE]> -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Put this in oyur html file

Comment: sorry alok that was a typo,my problem still persists.